# Image file posted not viewable when written to file

Tags: java, image, http, post

I'm sending an image file from an iPhone application to a http Post application.  The Post application is a java restful web service that accepts Post requests.  I have the Post method receiveing a byte array and then writing it to a file like this:

```
private void writeToFile(byte[] str) {
String strFilePath = "/Users/j/Desktop/joe.png";

try
{
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(strFilePath);

  fos.write(str);
  fos.close(); 
}
}
```

the file writes successfully to my local disk but when i attempt to open the file it is not viewable.  I get an error that it can't be open and may be damaged.  Does anyone know why I can't view this image?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from this information. If you upload the file in its correct and damaged forms, that might tell us more.

Comment: If the byte stream you receive hasn't got any PNG-headers, you will need to add them to your file, too, of course. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give you advice without seeing more of the code, but if all you're doing is writing the data directly to a file, you might as well skip storing it in a byte array and stream it directly to the output stream, as in this very simplified example:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( "myfile.jpg" );
InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
while( ( int ch = in.read() ) != -1 ){
    out.write( ch );
}
```

It's hard to give much more specific advice without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some sort of hickup with the discarting of the filehandler. It may be worth a try to invoke the garbage collector after closing the filestream.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

It helped me once at feleting files on win7.

At a last resort you can also try to verify that the rigth data is being send by computing a md5hash but http shouldn't lose data.